# Get id of the vehilce for which button was pressed

Tags: php, sql

I want to make some kind of booking system. I am displaying all data about cars from the database with buttons(which is a link that directs to the booking page) in "boxes", each box is for one car. I want to get id of the car for which the user pressed the button in box where the car is.

Here is my code

```
 <!-- Fetching data from rows -->
    <?php
        while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
    ?>
    <div class="car_box">
        <div class="car_title">
            <p><b><?php echo $rows['Brand'],' ', $rows['Model'];?></b></p>
        </div>

       <div class="car_description">
            <div class="car_details">
                
                <!-- ENGINE CAPACITY -->
                <p>
                    <b>Engine capacity: </b> <?php  echo $rows['Engine_capacity'];  ?> cm3
                </p>
    
               (...)
    
            <!-- BOOKING -->
            <div class="booking">
                <a href="../Bookings.php" class="book_now_button">Book now</a>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: What prevents you? And have you considered to use a HTML Form so that robots traversing the website wouldn't visit book-now links and book cars along the way?

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding a parameter to your link.

```
<a href="../Bookings.php?id=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>" class="book_now_button">Book now</a>
```

and retrieve it in your Bookings.php by using `$_GET['id']`.